# Use transitive dependencies and exclusions with Maven

Tags: maven

I have this maven hierachy :

```
sim-java
   ejb
   web
   log4j
   ...
```

ejb, web and log4j are modules of sim-java and each of these modules refer to sim-java by parent tag.

I would like to create a log4j module and include it as dependency in sim-java so log4j will be present as dependency in ejb and web modules.

Basically, my pom.xml inside sim-java contains this :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sim</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(scope is provided as I have an ear module which will include com.sim:log4j in ear file).

Now, my pom.xml inside my log4j module is this one :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have this build error :

> 30/10/12 18:56:07 CET: Build errors for log4j; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project log4j: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sim:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sim:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

I thought that there was some dependency problem since sim-java use com.sim.log4j as transitive dependency, so I tested that inside log4j pom.xml :

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sim</groupId>
        <artifactId>sim-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sim</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> 30/10/12 18:59:22 CET: [WARN] The POM for com.sim:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
>   30/10/12 18:59:22 CET: Missing artifact com.sim:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided
>   30/10/12 18:59:22 CET: Missing artifact com.sim:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided
>   30/10/12 18:59:22 CET: Missing artifact com.sim:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided

Perhaps including com.sim.log4j inside modules (ejb, web etc...) would work but I want to use transitive dependency via sim-java project.

How to do this please ?

Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the dependency on `com.sim:log4j` in the parent pom. That dependency will be inherited in the children meaning that `com.sim:log4j` will depend on itself.

Instead create a `<dependencyManagement/>` in the parent pom and then declare the use of `com.sim:log4j` in the children that needs it, here it is `web` and `ejb`.

Parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sim</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Web and Ejb pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sim</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**Edit**

You can still have a transitive dependency by only having the dependency on the log4j module from the ejb project. The web project will then have a dependency on the ejb project and the log4j will be a transitive dependency.

Comment: ok, I suspect this behaviour. This means that I have to include dependency manually inside all modules ? Thx

Comment: I added an edit section. I suspect that your web module depends on the ejb module. Thus if the ejb module has a dependency on log4j module it will be a transitive dependency in the web module.

Comment: thank you for this edit, I understand well and better dependencies now. Regards